# Run an executable in R script

Tags: r

Is there a way to run an executable from R and capture its output?

As an example:

```
output <- run_exe("my.exe")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, look at `system()` and its options. Hence

```
R> res <- system("echo 4/3 | bc -l", intern=TRUE)
R> res
[1] "1.33333333333333333333"
R>
```

would be one way to divide four by three in case you mistrust the R engine itself.

Comment: haha, reminds me of this https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/272562.html