# Pipe CSV stdout into read.csv

Tags: r, read.csv

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5410857/4068), say I have a console application that will write CSV data to standard out.

How can I use this with `read.csv` or some equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the `help(Connections)` documentation and 'just do it' :)

`read.csv()` can consume a URL via `url()`, output from a pipe via `pipe()` and even work files old-fashioned files.  There is an entire manual devoted to data input/output too.

Comment: Found that after I asked it...  Thanks!